# What are some popular anti sicilians and what are their respective strengths and weaknesses?

Tags: opening, theory, strategy, sicilian-defense

I dislike the positions in the sicilian in which both sides kamikaze each other. What are some popular anti sicilians which will bring the black players out of their comfort zone?

Answer (score 3):

For me it was very helpful to pick one opening (continuation) from moves available in big chess database like here

http://www.365chess.com/opening.php?m=3&n=3&ms=e4.c5&ns=3.3

I wouldn't recommend going with most common move  2.Nf3: that is what your opponent (a Sicilian player) is most used to, prepared and comfortable with.

For example Sicilian player played Smith Mora Gambit in less than one percent of all his games against 1.e4. But I played Smith Mora Gambit in 100% games against c5. Which can be considered an advantage.

Best thing is that you don't have to spend many hours studying all Sicilian dragons and other variations. But if your opponent wants to be ready for you he will have to study all variations of Smith Mora on top of all his previous studies of usual Sicilian theory.

(Don't forget to check sanity of variation with the best engine available.)

Comment: I disagree. Black can chose one of many defenses against the smith morra while white has to be ready for all of black's responses.I play it myself but I find that strong players usually have something prepared.

Answer (score 2):

First off when dealing with the Sicilian defense there is a lot of ground to cover and this question is very broad as the open Sicilian has 4 major variations and the closed Sicilian has at least 3 major variations that immediately come into my mind.

The following are good readings for anti-sicilians:

Alapin Variation,
Moscow Variation,
Rossolimo Variation,
Grand Prix Attack,
The Closed Sicilian (this has 3 major variations),
Smith-Morra Gambit,
Wing Gambit

Now if you wish to avoid the Sicilian entirely, you may want to consider switching your own opening strategy. As white and black I see the Sicilian a lot in online play, I started using the queens gambit as white to go into fresh lines of play which leads to a more relaxed build up of both players armies into the middle game, it also has several trapping lines that you can use to catch an uneducated player with.

I hope that helps, just keep in mind that when dealing with the Sicilian there is a lot of theory to cover and it is considered the most solid reply to white's king pawn opening.

References:

http://www.chess.com/blog/Torkil/anti-sicilians

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_chess#Anti-Sicilian